# GAC Assembly Reference in App.Config (Console Applications)

Tags: asp.net

I have a dll installed in GAC. I have not issues reading that assembly from asp.net applications the assembly reference i have done in web.config is able to refer to that assembly.

But in the console application, when i put the below in the app.config file, the solution gets compiled, but i am not able to access the dll from program.cs file.

Below is my app.config to refer to the dll in GAC.

```
<configuration>
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="myassembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9999999999999"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Where did that PublicKeyToken value come from?  The odds that it is all 9's is zippo.

Comment: Yes i know. I have not put the real public key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="filename"
                              publicKeyToken="999999999999"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <codeBase href="file:///C:\dir\filename.dll"/>


        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
```

You can also refer to this for reference:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/assemblydeployment.aspx?display=Print

Comment: But why do i need to reference the dll in the project. As the dll is in GAC, it should be available if we configure it in the app.config (that way it works for asp.net). so it should work without referencing it...right?

Comment: you shouldn't but figured it would be an easy fix, try changing your syntax to like the above

Comment: You do niot need it, but if it going to be shared within IIS you can use it to redirect:

http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2004/05/14/132022.aspx